# How to Find resources IDs

Tags: xml, android-layout, user-interface, lockscreen, android-lockscreenwidget

This Is My code.Here You Can See There Is Something "Android:id="resourceid:0×7f0a0396" Now My Question Is How Can I Find The File This resource is targeting. Because I Am Reverse Engineering My Stock Lock Screen To make it Something Different Hope You Got It.

```
`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="resourceId:0x7f0a0396" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1">

    <com.android.keyguard.KeyguardStatusView android:orientation="1" android:id="resourceId:0x7f0a0126" android:layout_width="410dp" android:layout_height="-2">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="1" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-2">

            <include android:id="resourceId:0x7f0a0267" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-2" layout="resourceId:0x7f0d00a6" />

            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="0x1" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:layout_marginTop="24dp" android:src="resourceId:0x7f080651" />

</LinearLayout>

</com.android.keyguard.KeyguardStatusView>

</FrameLayout>

`
```

I want to make my Lock screen like dotos 5.2 Android 11 but somehow that Android id Is just sucking alot Thanks In Advance